# XSLT Test whether any of keyed nodes exist

Tags: xslt

A variable `$rows` has a list of node ids that key into some source XML.

```
<row>
   <node id="d0113" />
   <node id="d0237" />
   <node id="d0321" />
</row>
<row>
   <node id="c0278" />
   <node id="d0137" />
   <node id="e0021" />
</row>
```

What is a good way to test, before processing each `<row>`, whether any of nodes keyed to actually exist in a node-set `$set`?

All I've come up with is

```
<xsl:for-each select="row">
  <xsl:variable name="test">  
    <xsl:for-each select="node">
      <xsl:value-of select="boolean($set//*[generate-id()=current()/@id]) * 1"/>
    </xsl:for-each>                  
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="$test&gt;0">
    <!-- go ahead and process the row -->
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   <xsl:value-of select="boolean($set//*[generate-id()=current()/@id]) * 1"/>
> ```

**This will in most cases return `false()` so this whole method of "indexing" is incorrect**.

This is because the values of `generate-id()` for any node in an XML document aren't guaranteed to be the same from transformation to transformation.

Even if in the provided XML document any `node/@id` attribute was generated to have the value of `generate-id()` on some particular node of the second document, nothing guarantees that in a consequent new transformation `generate-id()` on that same node will produce the same valu as the one that was used to generate the respective `node/@id`.

**Recommendation**:

For such indexing use a more stable function of a node -- one example of such function is the XPath expression that selects exactly that node.

If the document hasn' been modified, that XPath expression is going always to select that node.

**Update**:

In a comment the OP maintains that the `node/@id` attributes are both generated and used in the same transformation.

In this case, this single XPath expression produces a boolen that indicates whether or not `$set` contains at least one node whose `generate-id()` is one of the `node/@id` attributes of another document:

```
boolean($set[generate-id() = someExpression/row/node/@id])
```

In a `test` attribute of a conditional instruction, just the argument to `boolean()` above can be used.

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
$set[generate-id() = someExpression/row/node/@id])]
```

Selects all nodes in `$set` whose value of `generate-id()` is equal to at least one `someExpression/row/node/@id` attribute's value (someExpression here stands for the missing location steps about which we know nothing, since no XML document has been provided).

By definition, `boolean($someNodeSet)` is always `true()` if the node-set `$someNodeSet` contains at least one node, and is false if `$someNodeSet` is the empty node-set.

Comment: My simplifying misled. The variable is being created in the same run. So the id values are guaranteed to be the same. I can safely use generate-id. But even if a static key were used, the question is the same: how to speedily determine if a node set contains at least one node whose id appears in some list. (Ideally the search would even stop once one was found. My method makes a full scan.)

Comment: @JPM: See the update to my answer. This can be determined in a single XPath expression and no `xsl:for-each` is necessary.

Comment: Ah, yes! Because of how = works with node sets. Thanks Dimitre. +1, Q answered.